# CTRL+1 is not working

Tags: vbscript, ctrl

```
Option Explicit

Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Blackmagic Design\Blackmagic Media Express\MediaExpress.exe""" ,1,true

Wscript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "^1"

Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: And?  Do you just want to show off your code, or do you have an actual question?

Comment: Define "not working". What do result do you expect, and what result do you actually get? Also, note that `SendKeys` is a terrible method for application automation and should be avoided unless forced at gunpoint.

Comment: @roryap Sorry ,I forgot to mentioned that, The code is not working . Ctrl+1 is not working when i send using SendKeys.

Comment: @Ansgar  expected result:it should open window "Log and Capture" window from media express. I am getting nothing for "WshShell.SendKeys "^1" " . Do you know any other method/way instead of "SendKeys" ? Please share with me . I am new with VB script  :)

Comment: From a look at your code I would suspect that the keys simply don't go to the right window. Try putting an `WshShell.AppActivate "Media Express"` before the `SendKeys` statement (replace "Media Express" with the correct window title). As for other methods, from what I heard [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) should be both more reliable and more versatile than `SendKeys`, but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, I already tried WshShell.AppActivate but still Ctrl+1 is not working. Let me try AutoIt will work or not.

Answer (score 1):

`.SendKeys` method uses ***alphanumeric* keypad** for transmitting digits. My keyboard (the line with numbers under the uppermost <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>…</kbd> key row) behaves as follows (using Czech keyboard input):

<kbd>°</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> with <kbd>Shift</kbd>

<kbd>;</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>Ě</kbd><kbd>Š</kbd><kbd>Č</kbd><kbd>Ř</kbd><kbd>Ž</kbd><kbd>Ý</kbd><kbd>Á</kbd><kbd>Í</kbd><kbd>É</kbd> with <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>

<kbd>;</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>ě</kbd><kbd>š</kbd><kbd>č</kbd><kbd>ř</kbd><kbd>ž</kbd><kbd>ý</kbd><kbd>á</kbd><kbd>í</kbd><kbd>é</kbd> unmodified

I can confirm that e.g. `WshShell.SendKeys "^1"` (with `Windows Script Host Version 5.8`) sends **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>** keystrokes to the active window as if typed on the keyboard.

**My answer**: I need to use `WshShell.SendKeys "^{+}"` to emulate keyboard **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>** input.

Above `.SendKeys` behaviour is **independent** on current keyboard layout (input method) in *calling* `cmd` window (`cscript //nologo 34189495.vbs`) and in window activated right before `WshShell.SendKeys "^1"`. Tested *all combinations* of 
- Windows display language `English (UK)`, keyboard input method `Czech`/`United Kingdom` and 
- display language `Czech`, keyboard input method `Czech`/`US-international`,
each versus each other…

**Another problem**: how to emulate keyboard input **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>** using `.SendKeys` method? I can't use simply `WshShell.SendKeys "^{ě}"`. It does not work because `ě` (*latin small letter E with caron*) hexadecimal value is greater than `0x79` (and `ščřžýáíé` as well). As per [Keyboard Scan Code Specification](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjf-NrDp9LJAhVCDiwKHfC_C3gQFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F1%2F6%2F1%2F161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c%2Fscancode.doc&usg=AFQjCNFpwWwiM0iIlms4bSL-fVCvRK4K2w&sig2=_nCAYo_I5qHm90CcJgiS8A&bvm=bv.109395566,d.bGg&cad=rja) Microsoft document, *Prefixed Scan Codes* part (sorry for link to download):

> If you use scan codes from the `0xE0` set, make sure the second byte
>   is suitable in the same way as single byte scan code values. In other
>   words: **Not greater than `0x79`**, Not `0x60` or `0x61`, Not `0x00`…

However, here is a workaround: `WshShell.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}^{ě}{NUMLOCK}"` (who knows why it works? Derived from my previous experience with *keyboard wedge barcode scanners*!)

**Addendum**: tested using my preferred [text and code editor PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/en/);

Here is my working code:

```
option explicit
'On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo 0
Dim WshShell
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' WshShell.Run omitted, activate existing window (this script open in PSPad)
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.AppActivate "34189495.vbs"
WScript.Sleep 200
' Ctrl+Shift+3 set marker #3
WshShell.SendKeys "^3"
WScript.Sleep 100
' Ctrl+1 goto marker #1, i.e. move cursor to that line (pre)marked 1 
WshShell.SendKeys "^{+}"
' more time to observe 
WScript.Sleep 3000
' Ctrl+3 goto marker #3, i.e. move cursor to that line marked 3 
WshShell.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}^{Š}{NUMLOCK}"
WScript.Sleep 100
' more time before quit
WScript.Sleep 3000
Wscript.Echo Wscript.ScriptName
Wscript.Quit
```

Comment: Thanks @Josefz for good explanations.I tried "WshShell.SendKeys "^{+}" for CTRL+1 but it didnt work for me . I have same keyboard which you have it. ("the line with numbers under the uppermost EscF1… key row"). Please let me know if you know any other way to solve this.

Comment: @rrrppp [Take a look here: Windows Keyboard Layouts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964651.aspx) please. My answer is valid for [Czech](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/keyboards/kbdcz.html) but I guess that e.g. for [French](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/keyboards/kbdfr.html) it would change to `.SendKeys "^{&}"` (maybe modified with `{NUMLOCK}` trick). Or ``.SendKeys "^{!}"`` for English etc…

Comment: Thanks JosefZ and sorry for late reply. I am using US English Keyboard and according to layout 1 is 1 only. It tried with 1 but still it's not working.

Comment: @rrrppp did you try `!` exclamation mark as suggested?

Comment: Yeah I tried that too but no luck .. Do you have any other way to send keystrokes or any other idea ?

Comment: OMG, thank you man!I try send "^S" for Ctrl-S and it not work. After your answer I try "^s" now work nice! Thank you.